# Jmeter - testing multiple urls

Tags: load, jmeter, load-testing

I'm new to Jmeter; I would like to know how to test multiple urls (stored in a txt/csv file) of different sections of a website in a load test ie. is there any way to import that file and run a load test or any alternative solution?

Thanks!

LP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSV DataSet element which will on every iteration of main loop extract one line and put in the variable you will name.

Then put the var in path field of httpsampler.
If your var is named url, then you will put ${url}

Comment: I think it's working fine using the instructions provided but I just want to confirm if what I've done is correct:

STEP1. Create Test plan -> thread grp
 - thread grp -> Home page with IP
 -            -> Login page with user, pwd ; path set to http://../submit_login/
 -            -> Changes page with path set to ${url}

STEP 2: Test plan -> CSV data set config -> filename (loadtest_urls.csv), variables names: url

--- Run ---

I see results in the graph but I'm not sure how to interpret them.

Comment: What you did seems fine, you will need to read the manual: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html also look at http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/where-can-i-find-good-jmeter-tutorials , you can also upvote :-)

Answer (score 59):

This is how I did it. I have explained it step by step so that any newbie does not have to go through all the documents of Jmeter for figuring it out.

**Step 1: Create a Thread Group.**

[image]

I have named the Thread Group as **Demo Test Group**.

**Step 2: Create a While Controller**

[image]

A While Controller is created under the Demo Test Group.

**Step 3: Create a new variable named path in the condition section.**

[image]

**Step 4: Create a CSV Data Set Config**

[image]

The CSV Data Set config is created inside the While Controller.

**Step 5: Configuring the CSV Data Set.**

[image]

Make the changes as highlighted in the box. Inside the Filename section enter the csv file location.

The CSV file location should contain only the path. This is how my CSV file looked.

[image]

The value inside the Variable Names is same as the name of the variable in While Controller. Which is *path*.

**Step 6: Create HTTP Request**

[image]

Inside the While Controller create the HTTP Request.

**Step 7: Configuring the HTTP Request**

[image]

I have enter the Domain Name, the Protocol and in the Path section entered the variable {path}, which is picked from the CSV file.

**Step 8: Add View Results Tree**

[image]

You need to add the Listener under HTTP Request. Its purpose to listen to the responses.

**Step 9: Run Test**

[image]

The last step is to run the test.

You can see that the responses is been collected inside the **View Results Tree**.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Even though, I had different configuration (I did not use while controller), but your pictures helped me!

Comment: I have another component after while controller. But next component is not being executed as I am getting below exception:

__2021-02-24 20:23:29,317 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stop Thread seen for thread Thread Group 1-1, reason: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: End of file:C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/jmeter/urls.csv detected for CSVDataSet:CSV Data Set Config configured with stopThread:true, recycle:false__

Comment: In path field for me the variable is not being replaced. It's working fine if I want to use it in "Parameters" section, but not if directly want writing the varible into the Path field.

Answer (score 5):

Use the JMeter [`StringFromFile` function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile).

A very simple example: read from a file `c:/tmp/snip.txt` into a jmeter variable `myVar`.
Add a User Defined Variables config element to your test plan:

- name: myVar
- value: `${_StringFromFile(c:\tmp\snip.txt,myVar,,)}`

Then use the variable as `${myVar}` in your requests.

Comment: how do you loop through?